# MSBuild target for one framework only

Tags: build, msbuild, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a project with multiframework target- `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>`.

I want to build the solution for `netframework` and `netstandard` separately.

Currently I use this MSBuild command:

`MSBuild MySln.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /m /nr:False`

I tried tu run this command:

`MSBuild CxAudit.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:TargetFramework=netstandard2.0 /m /nr:False`
(with **/p:TargetFramework=netstandard2.0**)

But it failed, even the first command pass and build the `netstandard` output.

Comment: Have you tried `/p:TargetFrameworks=netstandard2.0` (with an `s`)?

Comment: Do you have projects in the solution that don't target `netstandard2.0`? I'm pretty sure the project that fails to build would be one of these other projects..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest setting a custom property and conditioning on these properties. This way, you won't affect other projects or references:

```
<TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(BuildNetStdOnly)' == 'true'">netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(BuildNetFxOnly)' == 'true'">net471</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(TargetFrameworks)' == ''">netstandard2.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>
```

This way you can build using

```
msbuild -p:BuildNetStdOnly=true -p:Configuration=Release -m -nr:false
msbuild -p:BuildNetFxOnly=true -p:Configuration=Release -m -nr:false
```

Note that this is setting the plural version only because `TargetFramework` needs to be set as global properties for the inner builds to work if the project was restored for both target frameworks. If you want to set the singular `TargetFramework`, you also need to restore again for each invocation, by passing the `-restore` argument to msbuild as well.